# Yum not found on Centos 7 " No module named yum"

Tags: centos, python, yum, error-handling

I recently installed CentOS 7 but have run into an issue with yum. I get the following error:

*There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
   No module named yum
Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.
It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.13 (default, Nov 15 2017, 23:42:24) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq*

What do I need to do to get yum working on my system?

Comment: How did you install CentOS 7?  This apparently is not a default install as CentOS does not offer Python v2.7.13.  You should not be changing the system supplied version of `python` but instead be using `virtualenv` to use different Python versions.  If you really have to use that version, then you have to find the matching `yum` libraries for that version which are probably in the same place you got your copy of Python from, but since you changed the system version of Python other things may be broken as well.

Comment: Welcome, please see the explanation here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21199.